# Django aggregate queries with expressions

Tags: python, sql, django, django-1.3

I have a model XYZ and I need to get the max value for fields a, b, and expression x/y for a given queryset.

It works beautifully for fields. Something like:

```
>>> XYZ.all().aggregate(Max('a'))

... {'a__max': 10}
```

However, I can't find a way to do it for expressions. Trying something like:

```
>>> XYZ.all().aggregate(Max('x/y'))
```

Gives an error:

```
*** FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'x/y' into field. Choices are: a, b, x, y, id
```

Trying something like:

```
>>> XYZ.all().aggregate(Max(F('x')/F('y')))
```

Gives an error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'split'
```

And even something like:

```
XYZ.all().extra(select={'z':'x/y'}).aggregate(Max('z'))
```

Also doesn't work and gives the same error as above:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'z' into field. Choices are: a, b, x, y, id
```

The one hack I found to do it is:

```
XYZ.all().extra(select={'z':'MAX(x/y)'})[0].z
```

Which actually works because it generates the right SQL, but it's confusing because I do get the right value at the z atttribute, but not the right instance, the one with that max value.

Of course, I could also use raw queries or tricks with extra() and order_by(), but it really doesn't make sense to me that Django goes all the way to support aggregate queries in a nice way, but can't support expressions even with its own F expressions.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You may be interested to know that the ability to use `F()` objects in aggregates is [part of the upcoming Django 1.8 release](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Version1.8Roadmap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL, what you want is actually

```
SELECT x/y, * FROM XYZ ORDER BY x/y DESC LIMIT 1;
# Or more verbose version of the #1
SELECT x/y, id, a, b, x, y FROM XYZ GROUP BY x/y, id, a, b, x, y ORDER BY x/y DESC LIMIT 1;
# Or
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE x/y = (SELECT MAX(x/y) FROM XYZ) LIMIT 1;
```

Thus in Django ORM:

```
XYZ.objects.extra(select={'z':'x/y'}).order_by('-z')[0]
# Or
XYZ.objects.extra(select={'z':'x/y'}).annotate().order_by('-z')[0]
# Or x/y=z => x=y*z
XYZ.objects.filter(x=models.F('y') * XYZ.objects.extra(select={'z':'MAX(x/y)'})[0].z)[0]
```

The version

```
XYZ.all().extra(select={'z':'MAX(x/y)'})[0].z
```

does not have correct x,y and instance because the `MAX` function is evaluated among all rows, when there is no `GROUP BY`, thus all instances in the returned QuerySet will have same value of `z` as `MAX(x/y)`.

Comment: Right, but the intent is to get the max value itself, as the return from XYZ.all().aggregate(Max('a')) does, not the instance containing it. The version with extra-select is the closest to it. Not returning the right instance is a confusing side effect, but it returns the right value. As I said in the opening message, I am aware of the solutions with extra and order_by, but these are not acceptable since they require a full sort of the table, not a single pass. It doesn't make much sense for Django to support Max aggregate with single fields but not expressions.

Comment: @pjwerneck The reason of the confusing side effect you called, is described in the last paragraph of my answer. If you only want max value, `XYZ.objects.extra(select={'z':'MAX(x/y)'})[0].z` is enough, there is no order_by. Or even directly `cursor.execute('SELECT MAX(x/y) from XYZ')`. I agree w/ you that Django does not provide aggregate w/ expressions, because it could be dramatically more difficult than supporting single field IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Your example that uses `F()` objects should work fine since Django 1.8:

```
XYZ.all().aggregate(Max(F('x')/F('y')))
```

There's a snippet that demonstrates aggregation with `Sum()` and `F()` objects in the [Django aggregation cheat sheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet):

```
Book.objects.all().aggregate(price_per_page=Sum(F('price')/F('pages'))
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For versions lower than 1.8 you can achieve the same in this (undocumented) way.

```
Book.objects.all().aggregate(price_per_page=Sum('price_per_page', 
                                                field='book_price/book_pages'))
```

This works for Postgres, I don't know about MySQL.

Source: [Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields)

Answer (score -3):

I think you should get the Maximum values separately

```
result = XYZ.aggregate(Max('x'), Max('y'))
```

And then divide the two fields

```
result['x__max'] \ result['y__max']
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Even if it returns the row with the max x and y pair, that isn't necessarily the max x/y. For instance, Max(x)/Max(y) row is 69/16=4, while max(x/y) is 8/1=8