# Django, find max of the sum of 2 fields

Tags: python, django

I have a model Django model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  fieldA = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  fieldB = models.IntegerField()
  fieldC = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to find the Max(fieldB + fieldC). Is there a Django way to do this? Or do I have to go with raw sql  (in case it will be something like "Select Max(fieldA + fieldB) From mymodel_table")?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *raw sql is Select Max(fieldB + fieldC) From mymodel_table..

Answer (score 7):

Here is a rather roundabout solution that should work, adapted from [Django aggregate queries with expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221422/django-aggregate-queries-with-expressions):

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'sum':'fieldB + fieldC'}).order_by('-sum')[0]
```

---

Original non-working answer (as of Django 1.4, F() expressions do not work in annotations)

You can use [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) and [annotation/aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations) to do this for you.  I think what you want is.

```
from django.db.models import F, Max
MyModel.objects.annotate(sum=F('fieldB') + F('fieldC')).aggregate(Max('sum'))
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it gives me an AttributeError -'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'lookup'

Comment: You're right...  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030.  Try the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221422/django-aggregate-queries-with-expressions.  Let me know if that works, and I'll update the answer.