# DRF: How to find the model instance with the highest combined value of two fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="likes",blank=True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="dislikes",blank=True)
```

I have added an endpoint in urls.py, so that when the url `.../v1/posts/max-interaction-count` is visited, the following function in views.py is run:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def interaction_count_view(request):
    max_post = None
    max_interactions = 0
    for post in Posts.objects.all():
        interactions = post.likes.count() + post.dislikes.count()
        if interactions > max_interactions:
            max_post = post
            max_interactions = interactions
    return Response({"Post number " :  max_post.pk, "interaction_count ": max_post.likes.count() + max_post.dislikes.count()})
```

This works, returning the id of the post with the maximum sum of likes and dislikes. However, I believe `interaction_count_view` might not be very scalable because it was written in python, rather than using built-in django methods which use SQL. Is this the case? If so, what is a better approach to counting the number of likes and dislikes associated with a post instance?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13477203/13964753

Comment: Do you mean "max_post.likes" and not "max_post.likes.count()". I don't think .count() would work on the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotate the expression calculating the number of interactions of a post on the queryset and use `latest` to get the post which has maximum number of interactions:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

@api_view(['GET'])
def interaction_count_view(request):
    max_post = Posts.objects.annotate(interactions=Count('likes') + Count('dislikes')).latest('interactions')
    if max_post:
        return Response({"Post number" :  max_post.pk, "interaction_count": max_post.interactions})
    return Response({"Post number": None, "interaction_count": 0, "message": "No posts exist!"})
```

> **Note**: I changed your keys in the dictionary that you pass to response they had extra spaces (`"Post number "` changed to => `"Post number"`, etc.)

> **Note**: Model names should ideally be **singular** so `Post` instead of <s>`Posts`</s>