# Aggregation of an expression in Django query spanning multiple tables

Tags: aggregate-functions, django-orm, table-relationships

Is it possible to compute an aggregation (ex.: sum) of an expression (ex.: subtraction) of fields from a **related table** in a Django ORM query?

For a full example of what I'm trying to achieve, see this working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8b395/13). I broke it down into two questions ([other one here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15453678/520779)). In this case, I have a model `Sequence` that represents a sequence of numbers, and a model `Part` that represent a "link" in this sequence:

```
Sequence   Sequence   Sequence   Sequence   ...
0          5          20         15         ...
|-- Part --|-- Part --|-- Part --|-- ...
```

Each `Part` thus represents a **delta**, which is the difference between the two values in the sequence. I have a set of (non-contiguous) parts and want to calculate the sum of those deltas. Something like this:

```
sum([p.after.value - p.before.value for p in Part.objects.filter(...)])
```

But in a single query (the reason is that I want to use this as a subquery for a more complex one). It's easy to do it in SQL:

```
select sum(a.value - b.value)
  from part p
    join sequence a on p.after_id = a.id
    join sequence b on p.before_id = b.id
  where condition
  group by p.other_field;
```

I don't know how to do it using Django ORM. I can do it for a single value:

```
Part.objects.filter(condition).aggregate(Sum('before__value')).values()
```

But not for an expression involving multiple values. Using `F()` [is not supported yet](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030), so I'm looking for an alternative way. I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10221422/520779), which is also about expressions in aggregates, but [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230338/520779) (using `extra`) is not applicable to my case AFAIK, since the fields I'm interested in are not in the same table, but in a related one.

```
>>> Part.objects.filter(condition).extra(select={
...     'delta':'sum(after__value - before__value)'
... })

DatabaseError: no such column: after__value
```

Here's a SSCCE, in case anyone want to experiment with it: [Download](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/aggregate_subquery.zip) or [Browse](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/sscce/). It has the same models and data as the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8b395/13) linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that 1.8 implemented [support for `F` expressions in `aggregate`](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030), the answer became straightforward:

```
Part.objects.filter(condition).aggregate(sum=Sum(F('after__value')-F('before__value'))).values()
```